# Kurtosis Inequality

Tags: probability

I´m trying to proof the following:

Proof that $Kur(X)$ $\geq-2$ with equality if and only if $\mathrm{P(X=1)=1/2}$ and $\mathrm{P(X=-1)=1/2}$.

Where $Kur(X)$ is the Kurtosis i.e. $Kur(X) = \frac{E((X-E(X))^4)}{(E(X-E(X))^2)^2}$.

For the first part I did this:

Note that  $E(X-E(X))^2 \ne 0 $ if $Kur(X)$ is well define. Let $Y$ be the random variable such that $Y=X-E(X)$. So we have:

$Var(Y^2) \geq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $E(Y^4)-[E(Y^2)]^2 \geq 0$

$\Rightarrow$ $E(Y^4) \geq [E(Y^2)]^2 $

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{E(Y^4)}{[E(Y^2)]^2} \geq 1$

So we subtract -3 in both sides and obtain what we desired. But I have troubles with the second part can anyone help me please...

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have E(X)=-1(1/2)+1(1/2)=0

and   $$E((X-E(X))^4)=E((X-0)^4)=E(X^4)=(-1)^4(1/2)+(1)^4(1/2)=1$$

Similarly
  $$    E((X-E(X))^2)=1$$

then

> $$\mathrm{kur}(X)=1/(1)^2-3=-2.$$